# How can a loop involving recursive multiplication and accumulation be vectorized?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization

In `matlab`, I have a loop of the form:

```
a=1;
for (i = 1:N)
   a = a * b(i) + c(i);
end
```

Can this loop be vectorized, or partially unrolled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `b` and `c` of length `4` each, when the loop is unrolled, you would have -

```
output = b1b2b3b4 + c1b2b3b4 + c2b3b4 + c3b4 + c4
```

So, the generic formula would be :

```
output = b1b2b3...bN + c1b2b3..bN + c2b3..bN + c3b4..bN + ... cN-1bN + cN
```

The cummulative product of `b` could be calculated with [`cumprod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html) with elements being flipped or "reversed". Rest is all about elementwise multiplication with `c` elements that are 1 place shifted and then including the remaining scalar elements from the cummulative product and `c` and finally summing all those up to get us the final scalar output.

So, the coded version would look something like this -

```
cumb = cumprod(b,'reverse');
a = sum(cumb(2:end).*c(1:end-1)) + cumb(1) + c(end);
```

---

### Benchmarking

Let's compare the loopy approach from the question against the vectorized one as proposed earlier in this post.

Here are the approaches as functions -

```
function a = loopy(b,c)
N = numel(b);
a = 1;
for i = 1:N
   a = a * b(i) + c(i);
end
return;

function a = vectorized(b,c)
cumb = cumprod(b,'reverse');
a = sum(cumb(2:end).*c(1:end-1)) + cumb(1) + c(end);
return;
```

Here's the code to benchmark those two approaches -

```
datasizes = 10.^(1:8);
Nd = numel(datasizes);

time_loopy = zeros(1,Nd);
time_vectorized = zeros(1,Nd);
for k1 = 1:numel(datasizes)
    N = datasizes(k1);
    b = rand(1,N);
    c = rand(1,N);

    func1 = @() loopy(b,c);
    func2 = @() vectorized(b,c);
    time_loopy(k1) = timeit(func1);
    time_vectorized(k1) = timeit(func2);
end

figure,
loglog(datasizes,time_loopy,'-rx'), hold on
loglog(datasizes,time_vectorized,'-b+'),    
set(gca,'xgrid','on'),set(gca,'ygrid','on'),
xlabel('Datasize (# elements)'), ylabel('Runtime (s)')
legend({'Loop','Vectorized'}),title('Runtime Plot')

figure,
semilogx(datasizes,time_loopy./time_vectorized,'-k.')
set(gca,'xgrid','on'),set(gca,'ygrid','on'),
xlabel('Datasize (# elements)'), ylabel('Speedup (x)')
legend({'Speedup with vectorized method over loopy one'}),title('Speedup Plot')
```

Here's the runtime and speedup plots -

[image]

[image]

**Few observations**

Stage #1: From starting datasize until 1000 elements, loopy approach has the upper hand, as the vectorized approach isn't getting enough elements to benefit from everything-in-one-go approach.

Stage #2: From 1000 elements until 1000,0000 elements, vectorized method seems to be the better one, as its getting enough elements to work with.

Stage #3: For the bigger datasize cases, it seems the memory bandwidth requirement of storing and working with millions of elements with vectorized approach as opposed to using just a scalar value with the loopy approach 
might be pegging back the vectorized approach.

**Conclusions:** If performance is the most important criteria, one can go with vectorized method or stay with the original loopy code based on the datasizes.